# How to make a list based on a string, ignore lowercase?

Tags: python, list

```
s = 'ABBCbDAbCdC'
a = 100
```

Using these, I want to make a list:

```
list = ['100', '101', '102', '103', '105', '106', '108', '110']
```

My main goal is to create a list of numbers starting from an integer  (`a =100` for example) corresponding to the letters in the string by ignoring the lowercase letters.

Is there any solutions to do this with python? I will apply the solution to a large file consisting of lots of fields and rows.

Comment: Yes, there are solutions to do this with Python; have you made any attempts yourself yet though? We can help you with your code here, not write the solution for you from scratch.

Comment: I addition to what @MartijnPieters said, it seems you have three basic problems to solve: *How to count the uppercase characters in a string* then *how to produce n consecutive integers* and finally *how to convert an integer into a string* . These three questions have answers  easily found online.

Comment: Sorry for taking your time, I am very very new in writing codes, trying to learn on my own, and probably did not know how to search in a correct way. Sorry for my silly question. thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to create a counter, the second argument is the starting value, letting you set it to `a` if you need that as a starting point.

To test if a string is uppercase, use the [`str.isupper()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper).

Combined together in a list comprehension with filter gives you:

```
[str(number) for number, char in enumerate(s, a) if char.isupper()]
```

This numbers all characters in `s` starting at `a`, but only includes those numbers in the output list where the character is uppercase; the numbers are converted to strings:

```
>>> s = 'ABBCbDAbCdC'
>>> a = 100
>>> [str(number) for number, char in enumerate(s, a) if char.isupper()]
['100', '101', '102', '103', '105', '106', '108', '110']
```

Answer (score 0):

Martijn's answer indeed the best. I have tried to make use of [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) functions<sup>1</sup>.

```
>>> filter(None,map(lambda x:str(x[0]) if x[1].isupper() else None,enumerate(s,a)))
['100', '101', '102', '103', '105', '106', '108', '110']
```

Do note that this is terribly slow compared to the List comprehension. Another `lambda` expression as [Pochmann](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013604/how-to-make-a-list-based-on-a-string-ignore-lowercase/30014892?noredirect=1#comment48150463_30014892) has mentioned below is `lambda x: x[1].isupper() and str(x[0])`. The difference between the two `lambda`s is negligible.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Any list comp can have an alternative using these functions</sub>

Comment: Alternative lambda: `lambda x: x[1].isupper() and str(x[0])`

Comment: @StefanPochmann I actually tried that logical operation, however it was a bit slow. So I settled for this

Comment: Hmm, I tried it as well now, and found no speed difference. Ran several tests, sometimes your expression won, sometimes mine. Difference was always very small.

Comment: Yeah. It was around 3 micro secs slow